# Compilng C/C++ makefile files under Windows (XP)

Tags: c++, windows, gcc, compiler-construction, makefile

I'm trying to use a Python library (pyMedia) that has some non-Python requisites libraries. (libogg, libvorbis, liblame, and libfaad2 - this isn't relevant to the question specifically).

libogg requires you to manually compile it from the source and comes with a makefile. I have GCC installed for Windows. How would I go about compiling this?

Answer (score 3):

Get [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/). It's the unix environment for windows, along with the Autotools (including make) toolchain.

Comment: I have Cygwin installed -- I should have been more specific though, I'm more confused on the command (as in what command and switches needed. I understand that may not be a simple answer, but if you could point me in the direction of a tutorial or sample syntax. 

I searched Google for it but all the guides assume your familiar with C programming and writing your own makefile, I couldn't really find a solution for understanding compiling process.

Comment: Generally, you run the configure script and then make. Configure populates the makefile with the variables that are relevant for your system, and make actually goes through the makefile and builds your piece of software. You can also try ./configure --help to see how you can customize the process. HTH.

Answer (score 1):

[MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) can be used to compile under Windows. Add the binary to the `PATH` environment variable and you can use `mingw32-make` to compile using the `Makefile`.